# Html.TextBoxFor format and css class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html.textbox

The two lines of code below work fine, but I want to combine them.
What I mean is: I want to use the @class in the first code line.
How can I do that?

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Price, String.Format("{0:f}", Model.Product.Price))%>

<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Name, new { @class = "textBox150" })%>
```

thanks,

Filip

Answer (score 75):

I know I'm way late here but I just found a solution to this issue:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "datepicker", Value=String.Format("{0:d}", Model.StartDate) })%>
```

Comment: @Cheddar - Thanks Man. This saved some hair on my head !

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no clean way to achieve this. There are a couple of possibilities:

1. Use an editor template for the Product property:

   ```
   <%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Product) %>
   ```

   and inside this editor template:

   ```
   <%: Html.TextBox("Price", string.Format("{0:f}", Model.Product.Price), new { @class = "textBox150" }) %>
   <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Name, new { @class = "textBox150" })%>
   ```
2. Write a custom helper that will append the class
3. Wrap those textboxes in a `span`:

   ```
   <span class="container150">
       <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Price, String.Format("{0:f}", Model.Product.Price))%>
       <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Name)%>
   </span>
   ```

   and then modify your CSS rule:

   ```
   .container150 input {
       // some rule that applies to the textbox
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Again, it may be late, but I believe that much better solution is to use [jquery.maskedinput](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) plugin (also available as a nuget package).

Why is it better to use a plugin than just an input format? Well, when someone modifies an input, you will loose formating, if you don't use a plugin.

[Here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) you can find a usage and a demo of how it works.